# Is it possible to perfrom the following transaction with DynamoDB?

Tags: java, transactions, amazon-dynamodb

I am working with DynamoDB using Java. I have 2 tables with me, say **Table1** and **Table2**.

**Table1** has items with attributes like this: <**attr1**, attr2, attr3>

**Table2** has items with attributes like this: <**attr3**, *attr4*, attr5>

[In the above 2 lines, the attributes in bold are partition keys and the ones in italic are range keys].

My API gets **attr1** as input, using that I will have to access an item from **Table1**, then using the **attr3** from the returned item, I will have to access an item from **Table2** (I have the **attr4** value available with me).

I want these 2 steps to be completed as a transaction.

Is it possible to perform this type of transaction in DynamoDB?

**TransactionLoad**, seems to be promising but I couldn't find a way to specify that I want a particular item from the **Table1**, using the **attr1** value and then using the **attr3** value obtained, get the item from **Table2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I would like to point that DynamoDB (or any non SQL) it's not suited for that kind of operations, and multiple tables: [NoSQL Design for DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-general-nosql-design.html)

And about your question, the transactional read posibilities of DynamoDB are [TransactGetItems](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_TransactGetItems.html), where you can read from multiple tables, but it´s not possible to make a transaction that read 1 table, and with the results read another, in fact by definition those are 2 transactions.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the accepted answer, it looks like you're trying to implement joins using a NoSQL database.

One of the defining differences between SQL and NoSQL solutions is the normalization of your data.  In SQL, we often normalize the data and use SQL to combine the data into the structure our application needs.  This can become problematic at scale, as doing complex joins (or other unbounded SQL queries) can make it difficult to predict performance at scale.

NoSQL databases, on the other hand, typically *denormalize* data to match the specific needs of our application. This approach eliminates the need to join data across tables and improves performance at scale.

The approach you are describing in your question is a blend of these two approaches.  You are using NoSQL to store your data in a normalized fashion and are simulating a join in your application code (because DDB does not give you joins).  While this approach may make sense in certain scenarios, it suggests that you *may* not be modeling your data optimally for a NoSQL database.

The "NoSQL" way of achieving what you're after is to store the data in Table1 and Table2 in the same partition (in the same table).